# Possible to get a static modal to close in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

We have a page where a client wants the modal to be visible on page view.  I've run into the problem where the bootstrap modal doesnt close unless you launch it manually

Am I doing something wrong?  If you click launch modal (even tho the modal is already visible) you can then close it

Here's the HTML:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>​
```

The CSS is just the Bootstap stuff. We're not using any JavaScript code for this at all.

[Live copy on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgHBw/2/)

Comment: Live links are great, but always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: On the jsfiddle I only see the modal opened

Comment: I've moved the markup into the question for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not "launching" the modal, you just have inline markup that's visible. The modal hasn't really been opened at all.

Make the modal hidden (add `style="display: none"` to the `#myModal` `div`) and then trigger opening it using [`.modal('show')`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) from `ready`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');​​
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgHBw/3/)

That will hook up the required handlers for the close button, position it properly, do the background overlay, etc.

Comment: thx wasnt aware bootstrap had to launch via js inorder for those hooks to get set